# Can't run Gatsby develop on existing project on Mac M1

Tags: arm, gatsby, apple-m1

When running Gatsby develop on a project, it doesn't run. This is everything I get: (not very verbose)

```
my-project [master●] % gatsby develop
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.052s
⠋ load plugins
[1]    77411 killed     gatsby develop
```

For context, the project was developed on an older Mac and runs without problems there (or on two other peoples' non-M1 macs). Installing and running a new Gatsby site is seamless.

Previously I had trouble getting this project to run, when running `npm install`, which I was able to fix by reinstalling brew vips and xcode-select.

But this doesn't throw an error... so I have no idea what's going on.

I tried installing vscode insiders, but no luck there.

Any clues as to what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

same issue here.

I ended up re-installing brew and that made the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The flow which i tried got worked for me, also i had posted you the configuration which i had previously.

```
brew reinstall vips
xcode-select --install
brew install gcc
brew reinstall vips
brew info vips
npm i
```

**System Informations:**

- Gatsby CLI version: 4.0.0
- Gatsby version: 3.14.6
- Node version: v14.18.0
- NPM version: 6.14.15